# Best way to exit iOS application after tests

Tags: ios, testing, exit

In my iOS app, I have a webview.
In the project, there is a specific target that runs integration test for javascript and native code communication. These tests are written in javascript, and ran inside the WebView.

I can detect when javascript is done testing. What I'd like to do is exit the application, so that the `xcodebuild -scheme MyJSTests` would run and exit properly.

**What's the best way to exit an iOS application when the tests are done?**

EDIT:
I have no choice on the test framework whatsoever, as we receive the test files from another project. All I can do is implement a method that's responsible for reporting and exiting.

The tests are executed in full javascript, inside the webview. The test scripts are loaded through a custom URLProtocol. At the end of the tests, a method call `reportResults()` is done, that is forwarded to native code.

Comment: What test framework are you using? How are the tests executed?

Comment: See the edit. Actually the test framework should not matter here, as it could change in the future. The only sure thing is that I'll get a call to a specific method that's responsible for reporting and exiting.

Answer (score -2):

It is against apple's guidelines to end a program through code. Exiting a program by their guidelines should be done only by the user, otherwise it can be interpreted as an undesired action by the user.

Comment: He's talking about a test environment; I think it's OK to violate a couple of guidelines here.